# Hive. Over partition by vs Having-clause

Tags: hive, having-clause

I have following table:

```
column0  column1      column2 column3 column4
sunny    hot         high    false   no
sunny    hot         high    true    no
overcast hot         high    false   yes
rainy    mild        high    false   yes
rainy    cool        normal  false   yes
rainy    cool        normal  true    no
```

I want to run the query with having-clause and  OVER PARTITION BY ,my query is

```
SELECT column0,column1,column2,count(column0) OVER (PARTITION BY column2) AS cnt FROM FF_weatherdatase1  where column0="sunny"  having cnt>8
```

But hive shows :

```
 HAVING specified without GROUP BY error.
```

please provide method to run having-clause  using over partition by condition without group by condition, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` can be used only with `GROUP BY` . For your query, you can use a `where` condition outside parentheses.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT column0,
               column1,
               column2,
               COUNT(column0)
                 OVER (
                   PARTITION BY column2) AS cnt
        FROM   ff_weatherdatase1
        WHERE  column0 = 'sunny') w
WHERE  cnt > 8
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can we use  over partition used instead of having clause?

Comment: The two are not directly related and it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you can provide the expected output in your question, we may suggest the better solution for your need.

Comment: when we are trying previous query using hive context  in Apache spark it works but same query directly run with hive got :HAVING specified without GROUP BY error. And our hive version is hive-0.14.0